# Are methods exactly the same for each instance of a class, or can they be different?

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I have a piece of code that computes mass and density profiles for dense stars. In it, each instance method contains a set of if-then statements which - depending on the star and the model - choose the appropriate mathematical expression. I will append the entirety of the more general piece of code at the bottom, but an abridged version should do nicely for now.

```
class Star(object):
    def __init__(self,startype,relativity)
        self.star = startype
        self.r = relativity            

    def integration(self):
        if self.r == 'Galilean': 
           if self.star == 'White Dwarf':
                return simple_expression
           elif self.star == 'Neutron Star':
                return complicated_expression

        elif self.r == 'Einstein':
           ...

'''Make a star'''
neutronEinstein = Star(startype='Neutron',relativity='Einstein')

'''Call integration method'''
Mass = neutronEinstein.integration()
```

The problem here is that every time the integration method is called, those if-then statements must be evaluated, and this slows down the execution of the code by a significant amount - compared to a more specialized implementation, the code runs slower by an order of magnitude. I have tried to place the if-then statements outside of the definition, like so

```
    if self.r == 'Galilean': 
        if self.star == 'White Dwarf':
            def derivativeOfMass(self):
                return simple_expression
```

but that doesn't work because self isn't recognized. I find it confusing that I can - in a sense - 'call' self with `def foo(self):` in the body of my class, but I can't reference it there. Although I think I understand it correctly if I say that the reason why I can't reference it directly there, is that 'self' is a place holder for the instance(s) of the class yet to be created, rather than a run of the mill variable?

Another thing I'm curious about is if each instance of the class has it's own set of methods - that is to say, if I make

```
neutronEinstein = Star(startype='Neutron',relativity='Einstein')
neutronGalilean = Star(startype='Neutron',relativity='Galilean')
```

do those two instances of the Star class both have the exact same instance method 'integrate()', or is it possible for each of them to - in essence - have one separate 'integrate()'?

So to sum up, I want to make a program that lets me do

```
MassE = neutronEinstein.integration()
MassG = neutronGalilean.integration()
```

in such a way that the instance method integration() is different in each of those two cases. Is this possible? If so, how - and if not, is there another straightforward way to avoid the problem of repeat if-then evaluations at every function call?

You can find a python 2.7.6 runable version of my script here: [main](https://pastebin.com/ziwGydRi),
[constants](https://pastebin.com/1ZSZzc9j)

Comment: Polymorphism is what you're looking for, or in case of Python even better - duck typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using instance attributes to simulate inheritance, instead of using inheritance directly.

```
class Star(object):
    pass

class Galilean(Star):
    pass

class Einstein(Star):
    pass

class WhiteDwarf(Galilean):
    def integration(self):
        return simple_expression

class NeutronStar(Galilean):
    def integration(self):
        return complicated_expression

'''Make a star'''
neutronEinstein = NeutronStar()

'''Call integration method'''
mass = neutronEinstein.integration()
```

Comment: So in your example, I would explicitly place the most general attributes in the Star class, the ones specific to Einstein in the Einstein class, etc?

Comment: Precisely. Further, any code expecting an instance of `Star` should continue to work if given an instance of a subclass of `Start` instead.

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a method in Star which calls on the integration() method. Would it be possible to reverse the hierarchy of inheritance? For reference you can search for RK38 in the script I linked at the bottom of OP, which uses dMdr, and dPdr.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a way. Though I'm still feel like I don't know what I'm doing, so there's sure to be other ways!